# How to change border of image on multiple Selection in gridviewlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, background-image

Hi i am making whatsapp cleaner app .
This is my adapter Class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
        ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
        this.c = c;
        this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return spacecrafts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return spacecrafts.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v=null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(view==null)
        {//INFLATE CUSTOM LAYOUT
          v = new View(c);
          v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.whatsimage, null);

            final Spacecraft s= (Spacecraft) this.getItem(i);
          TextView nameTxt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            ImageView img= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);

            //BIND DATA
            nameTxt.setText(s.getName());
            Picasso.get().load(s.getUri()).into(img);
            //VIEW ITEM CLICK

        }

    else {
            v = (View) view;
        }

        return v;
    }

}
```

This is my Item Class.

```
public class Spacecraft {

    String name;

    private Uri uri;;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }


}
```

I am using   gv.Multiplechoice for selection but when  i click on items the items does not gets highlighted.
I want to highlight the images while click.
I am new to android programming so i cannot figure out how can i achive this.?
Can anybody please help me and provide the better solution.

```
  gv.setAdapter(adapter);
       gv.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        gv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
      count=count+1;
      mode.setTitle(count+" Deleted Items");
        list_items.add(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater=mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_open:

       int i;
                for ( i= 0; i < list_items.size(); ++i) {
                    Spacecraft s1 = list_items.get(i);
                    File f = new File(s1.getUri().getPath());
                    Boolean deleted = f.delete();
                    GridViewLayout.this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(s1.getUri().getPath()))));
                    if (deleted == true) {
                         list_items.remove(i);
                         list.remove(s1);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(GridViewLayout.this, count +"Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               count=0;
               mode.finish();

                return true;

                default:  return  false;
            }

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add flag isSelected property in Spacecraft for using in your CustomAdapter. You can visible something to show the border base on flag isSelected

After you change the flag you need notify data set change first.